Конвейер с динамическим вычислением нескрытых файлов в Linux
В данный момент я пытаюсь написать команду, которая в конец файла results.txt допишет строку вида: текущее количество нескрытых файлов и директорий в /usr/bin равно: 1234, где число 1234 динамически вычисляется по действительному количеству нескрытых файлов и директорий в данном каталоге.
В задаче нельзя использовать объединение некскольких команд через ; или && или ||.
Для вывода текста можно использовать команду echo.
Я почти написал эту команду. В ней не работает динамический подсчёт файлов. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Вот моё решение:
ls -la /usr/bin |wc -l |echo "текущее количество нескрытых файлов и директорий в /usr/bin равно: " >results.txt

Затем читаю файл cat results.txt.

Наверно echo "текущее количество нескрытых файлов и директорий в /usr/bin равно:" $(ls -1 /usr/bin | wc -l) >> results.txt

@andreyamal,благодарю!
Скажи пожалуйста,существует ли возможность упростить данную команду?
